# How could GeneratedMethodAccessor access private methods?

Tags: java

As we know, Java use GeneratedMethodAccessor to optimize reflection method call. In implementation,
Java will generate a GeneratedMethodAccessorXXX class instance to proxy the actual method call. However, since the class should still obey the method accessing rule, then what happens if target method has private modifier?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when a method is accessed using reflection, the normal access rules are bypassed, and it's possible to invoke even private methods. This is usually achieved through the setAccessible() method from the AccessibleObject class, which allows overriding the access checks for methods, fields, and constructors.

When invoking a private method using reflection, you can use the Method.setAccessible(true) method to change the accessibility of the method to true, thus allowing it to be invoked despite its private modifier. For example:

```
   import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PrivateMethodAccess {
    private void myPrivateMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is a private method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrivateMethodAccess obj = new PrivateMethodAccess();

        Method method = PrivateMethodAccess.class.getDeclaredMethod("myPrivateMethod");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Bypass the access checks

        method.invoke(obj); // Invoking the private method
    } }
```

In the case of GeneratedMethodAccessor (part of Java's reflection mechanism used for optimization), if it's used to invoke a private method, it internally sets the accessibility to true for that method to bypass the access checks.

However, changing the accessibility of private methods using reflection is generally discouraged unless absolutely necessary because it breaks encapsulation and can lead to unexpected behavior. It's important to understand the implications and use such mechanisms judiciously to avoid introducing security vulnerabilities or violating the intended behavior of classes and objects.